# jQuery bug - $(el).css('float') when absolute or fixed - different browsers return different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, css-float

if an element is `floated` and has a position of `absolute` or `fixed` and the script `$(el).css('float')` is run Chrome will return ***"left"*** but all other major (up-to-date) browsers return ***"none"***.

Why is this? How can I work around this?

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/ChPCD/7/ < run in different browsers

EDIT: thanks Explosion Pills with the technical answer. Changed my script to switch the positioning to static briefly to grab the previously float value. Still think the results to be the same cross-browser =P

Comment: It seems to me that you shouldn't use `absolute` or `fixed` as those are invalid.

Comment: @ExplosionPills why would `absolute` or `fixed` be invalid?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float

Comment: @ExplosionPills is right; "This property specifies whether a box should float to the left, right, or not at all. It may be set for any element, *but only applies to elements that generate boxes that are not absolutely positioned.*"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of cross browser support.

Your two options are:

1) Write browser specific code. Use some method for detecting the current browser and execute code specific to that browser.

2) Find another way. For example rather than say checking the float value you could look for a specific class or other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that since [`absolute` or `fixed` positioning overrides `float` behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float), different browsers are returning different values of the overridden property: discarding it outright or preserving it.

Maybe you could use a different method to find those elements: perhaps a jQuery selector based on the same rule that applied the `float` in the first place, for example:

**CSS**  `div.float-left{float:left;}`

**jQuery** `$('div.float-left').each(foo);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no float if you use `position: absolute;` . Maybe it useful to you one of

```
parseInt( $(el).css( 'left' ), 10)
```

or

```
$(el).position().left
```